# How to format the timeseries axis of a matplotlib plot like a pandas plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, axis, xticks

I've created following graph with `pd.Series([1]*month_limits.size, month_limits).plot(ax=ax)`
How do I recreate same x ticks labels with just matplotlib? I mean years and month not overriding each other
[image]

Best I got is having years and months at the same time, but years are overriding months

```py
import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

month_limits = pd.date_range('2021-08', '2023-01', freq="1m",
                             normalize=True) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
plt.plot(month_limits, [1]*month_limits.size)

l1 = mdates.YearLocator()
l2 = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(l1)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(l2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(l1))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(l2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `set_minor_locator` and `set_minor_formatter` for the month `'%b'`
- Use `set_major_locator` and `set_major_formatter` for the month and year `'%b\n%Y'`

  - `mdates.YearLocator(month=1)` where `month` is the month that shows the year.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`**

```py
month_limits = pd.date_range('2021-08', '2023-01', freq="1m", normalize=True) +  pd.Timedelta(days=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax.plot(month_limits, [1]*month_limits.size)

# set locators
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=2))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(month=1))
# set formatters
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b\n%Y'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

[image]

```py
month_limits = pd.date_range('2021-08', '2023-01', freq="1m", normalize=True) + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax.plot(month_limits, [1]*month_limits.size)

# set locators
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=range(1, 13, 3)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(month=1))
# set formatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b\n%Y'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

[image]